# GluonFX fails with native run and xcode 15 and ios17

Tags: gluon-mobile, gluonfx

I submitted a ticket at https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin/issues/493

And wondering if anyone has any ideas either how to fix this issue or how to manually debug from my native device to my computer.

The application works fine running on the desktop but fails when I run it on the ipad.

I'm not sure why since I can't see logs.